# C# response object reference not set while calling SAP webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, sap-basis

I have a web service in SAP and I have to make a C# client to the web service. I create the client but I receive an error from `C#`. Error is this :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My source for client is this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://address");
var address = new EndpointAddress(uri, EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("teste"));
ServiceReference2.ZWS_PEP_ENVIO_MRZClient wsclient = new ServiceReference2.ZWS_PEP_ENVIO_MRZClient();
//  wsclient.Endpoint.Binding.Scheme;
wsclient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user_name";
wsclient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
wsclient.Endpoint.Address = address;
wsclient.Open();


ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrz request = new ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrz();
request.Descricao = descricaoField;
request.Mrz1 = mrz1Field;
request.Mrz2 = mrz2Field;
request.Numeroprocesso = numeroprocessoField;
request.Sn = snField;
request.Statusdatapreparation = statusdatapreparationField;
request.Versaodocumento = versaodocumentoField;

wsclient.ZwsPepEnvioMrz(request);
ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse1 response = new ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse1();
Resultado = response.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse.ToString();
textBox1.Text = Resultado;


wsclient.Close();
```

And the program terminates at

```
Resultado= response.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse.ToString()
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Add breakpoint and look which variable `response` or `response.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse` is null.

Comment: Either `response` or `response.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse` is null. Easiest way is to attach a debugger.

Comment: I add a breakpoint and response.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse is null,because this varaible revice a response from SAP, but i don't get the response

Answer (score 0):

this won't work:

```
wsclient.ZwsPepEnvioMrz(request);
ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse1 response = new  ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse1();
```

you can't create a new response object yourself and expect it to contain any data. The response object should be the result from your web service call. I can't check this as the types are specific to your web service, but if the ws method ZwsPepEnviroMrz returns an object of type ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse1 you should try this:

```
ServiceReference2.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse1 response = wsclient.ZwsPepEnvioMrz(request);
```

now the `response` variable should contain some data and this

```
Resultado = response.ZwsPepEnvioMrzResponse.ToString();
```

should work.